# My Server Experiencing High Load Average & High Sleeping Task

Tags: nginx, centos7

My server load average is high, as well as the high sleeping task. 
What do I do? Should I terminate the sleeping process? What's the best way?

Because basically, my web application cannot be accessed and it's very slow. I should add that the load average can get to 20, 30, etc.

Background info: My server is a 4core server, linux CentOS, 8GB RAM.

Please help! Thank you.

We tried to search for any background processes and stopped some that are not in use. I wonder if I should stop the sleeping processes?

Here is the result of the top code:

```
top - 00:19:57 up 884 days,  6:58,  1 user,  load average: 8.66, 12.39, 16.79
Tasks: 659 total,   2 running, 657 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.5 id, 24.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7904908 total,  1783236 free,  1534192 used,  4587480 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8142844 total,  8110288 free,    32556 used.  5607916 avail Mem
```

Then, I tried to see what those sleeping processes are, and it's a very long list. Here's a sample:

```
[kthreadd]
[ksoftirqd/0]
[kworker/0:0H]
[migration/0]
[rcu_bh]
[rcuob/0]
[rcuob/1]
[rcuob/2]
[rcuob/3]
[rcuob/4]
[rcuob/5]
[rcuob/6]
[rcuob/7]
[rcuob/8]
[rcuob/9]
[rcuob/10]
[rcuob/11]
[rcuob/12]
[rcuob/13]
[rcuob/14]
[rcuob/15]
[rcuob/16]
[rcuob/17]
[rcuob/18]
[rcuob/19]
[rcuob/20]
[rcuob/21]
[rcuob/22]
[rcuob/23]
[rcuob/24]
[rcuob/25]
[rcuob/26]
[rcuob/27]
[rcuob/28]
[rcuob/29]
[rcuob/30]
[rcuob/31]
[rcuob/32]
[rcuob/33]
[rcuob/34]
[rcuob/35]
[rcuob/36]
[rcuob/37]
[rcuob/38]
[rcuob/39]
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
[kworker/1:1]
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
top
[kworker/3:1]
[kworker/0:1]
[kworker/u480:2]
[kworker/3:3]
sshd: andi [priv]
sshd: andi@notty
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
[kworker/2:0]
[kworker/1:0]
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
[kworker/2:3]
[kworker/3:0]
[kworker/3:2]
sshd: andi [priv]
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
[kworker/1:2]
local -t unix
bounce -z -t unix -u
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm: pool www
trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -s 3
smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -s 3
grep --color=auto ^[SD]
cut -b 3-
/usr/sbin/lvmetad -f
```